# Error "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid" with Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-b2c

We're using **Azure AD B2C** with our **Xamarin Forms** app. I've got this working on *Android* and had it working on *iOS*. For some strange reason though I'm now getting this error when trying to login on *iOS*.

[image]

The login screen comes up, the user enters their username and password, but then they get the error. Looking at the **Azure** sign-ins for the AD I can see that **Azure** has successfully signed-in the user. This suggests the error is with the redirection back to the app from **Azure**.

I've configured the app according to this [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native) especially step 6. Like I said though, I had this working previously. I haven't changed any of the login code since getting it working, so what else could have caused it to break?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add this method to your `AppDelegate.cs`

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication application, NSUrl url, string sourceApplication, NSObject annotation)
    {
        if (HandleOpenURL(application, url)){
            return true;
        }

        //return base.OpenUrl(application, url, sourceApplication, annotation);
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I'll give that a go and see how I get on. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately that has failed to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found the answer by referring to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c). The pertinent section is the iOS section describing updating the *info.plist* file. The example article I used to integrate with **Azure AD B2C** (see my OP above) stated that I should use a text editor such as VS Code to update this file. However, the article here states I should update the file using *Visual Studio*. A comparison of the two files shows differences between the values entered into *info.plist*.

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>My URL scheme</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>msalmyapplicationid-goes-here</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>None</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

This logged me in but then I immediately got the following error which kicked me out of the app.

**The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection**

I added the following to info.plist whihc has resolved the error.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

All is now working and users can log into the app using iOS.